# check if directory is empty before find

Tags: linux, sh

I have this function which deletes all files and folders in a directory except `.gitignore`, but if the directory is already empty I get some warnings. How to suppress the warnings or do a check before `find`?

The directory is not a git repository

```
rm_exclude_gitignore (){
    find $1 -maxdepth 0 -type d -exec rm -rf {} +
    find $1 -maxdepth 0 -type f ! -name '.gitignore' -exec rm {} +
}

rm_exclude_gitignore '/path-to-something/*'
```

output

```
find: ‘/path-to-something/*’: No such file or directory
find: ‘/path-to-something/*’: No such file or directory
```

Comment: There are legitimate use cases for such a script, but just in case: are you aware of the `git clean` command?

Comment: @thomas its not a git repository

Comment: You should quote your variable expansions. pass `/path-to-something/*` (without quotes) and then use `"$@"` in your function (with quotes).

Answer (score 0):

You can find non-empty directories with `find -type d -not -empty`

NB: you should always quote your variables when expanding. Let callers handle glob expansion.

```
rm_exclude_gitignore () {
    # add quotes:
    find "$@" -maxdepth 0 -type d -not -empty -exec rm -rf {} +
    find "$@" -maxdepth 0 -type f ! -name '.gitignore' -exec rm {} +
}

rm_exclude_gitignore /path-to-something/* # remove quotes
```

(be aware of the potentially disastrous effects of `rm -rf`!)

If you only want to *suppress* the error message, redirect stderr to `/dev/null`: `2>/dev/null` after each command which should have its errors suppressed. But it's better to avoid generating the errors altogether, so that you do not miss other important errors.

Comment: What do you mean by "disastrous effects of `rm -rf`` ?

Comment: From the question, does it make more sense to do those operations in the opposite order?  Recursively delete all the files that are not `.gitignore` and then purge all the empty directories?

Comment: @clarkk it will delete directories including all subdirectories and files. If you pass the wrong argument or your find finds the wrong files, you could easily wipe your complete home directory.

Comment: @clarkk  `rm -rf` recursively and indiscriminately deletes all files.

Comment: @knittl I'm aware of `-rf` :) Thought there was some other things I needed to be aware of

Comment: @knittl What does `$@` do?

Comment: @knittl I still get the warnings.. I call the function like this `rm_exclude_gitignore $local_bak_data_import/*`

Comment: and of cource use `find "$@" ... ` in the function

Comment: @clarkk `"$@"` is all arguments to a function. And hmmm, yes, you are right. Shells will not replace the glob if no files match. You will want to look at `shopt` for how to tune the globbing behavior (fail, resolve to empty, etc.). Or just suppress the error